# How to rigorously establish this limit of sums

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits

Assuming that $$\lim_{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du,$$ (where $f$ is $C^2$ and $g$ and $g_n$ are probability distribution functions) I want to prove that:
$$\lim_{n}\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(u_n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du,$$
where $u=(u_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence such that $\lim_{n} u_n=1$. My first idea is to write:
$$\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(u_n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du=\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(u_n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)-\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)+\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)-\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du.$$
Obviously the second difference above tends to zero by assumption, and my thoughts are that the first difference should tend to zero also, but I am unsure how to establish this rigorously. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think we need some assumptions on $f$ and $g$ to really be able to say anything meaningful here. Are they $L^2$ functions? Are they in $L^1\cap L^2$?

Comment: $f$ is assumed to be $C^2$ and $g$ and $g_n$ are probability distribution functions

Comment: I feel like I've seen a pretty similar question to this one quite some time ago but I don't know how to find it. You should add those assumptions to your post so that others will see it.

Comment: Is there some kind of relationship between $g_n$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider $[-r,r]$ for large $r$. Note $f$ is uniform continuous on $[-r,r]$. So for any $\epsilon>0$, there is $\delta$, for any $|x-y|<\delta$, there is $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Since $u_n\to1$, there is $N$, such that for all $n>N$, 
$|u_n-1|<\delta$. And for all $k$, $|u_n\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n}}-\dfrac{k}{\sqrt{n}}|<2r\delta$, and
$$
\left|f\left(u_n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right|<\epsilon
$$
So we have
\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(u_n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)-\sum_{k\geq 0} f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)g_n (k)\right|&=\left|\sum_{k\geq 0} \left(f\left(u_n\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-f\left(\frac{k}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\right)g_n (k)\right|
\\
&<\epsilon\sum_{k\geq 0}|g_n (k)|
\\
&<M\epsilon
\end{align}
because $g_n$ is probability distribution function and integrable.

Also note that there exists $M'$ that for all $r>M'$
$$
\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du-\int_{[-r,r]} f(u)g(u)\mathsf du\right|<\epsilon
$$

Comment: yes, I would just add that $M=1$ since $g_n$ is a pdf

Comment: just one thing hermes, is there a specific argument which enables us to conclude that we can extend the result to $\mathbb{R}$, or is it just obvious since the proof holds on any compact interval?

Comment: Nothing else. Just because $r$ is arbitrary large, it can be any point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ok thanks, this might be obvious but can we always extend a result like this which holds on an arbitrary compact interval to the non compact real line?

Comment: ok now I understand better, thanks man